# Xcode Sever Bot Automate Git Pull

Tags: xcode, git, xcode-server, xcode-bots

I have a Xcode server instance with a bot that runs a few operations. I would like to add `git pull`.

I have tried a few basic solutions that have failed.  Looking for suggestions if this is possible. If so is there a script example, if not what would be an alternative?

Comment: What is the value of having a passphrase if you're just going to hard-code it into a bot? Depending on your exact use case, an SSH key without a passphrase may be just a secure.

Comment: I have added it to my keychain access, will update question.

Comment: So what is your question? "Is it possible to have a bot run `git pull`?" Yes, of course it is. But under what conditions to you want this to happen? What are the "few basic solutions that have failed"? What is your end goal here? Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627) and also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a shell script outside of Xcode, then the bot would call that script for a typical `git pull`.